# Show highlighted Dates in react Datepicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

I am using **react datepicker** in my react component. I have to show dates highlighted which are coming from api. I am getting the array of dates from api like below:

> ["2019-01-03T18:30:00.000Z","2019-01-03T18:30:00.000Z"]

I am mapping above array and using `subDays` function inside the map function to create the array of dates and pass it to `highlightDates` property inside datepicker. But it is giving me **subDays is undefined** error.

Can anyone please tell me, How can i highlight the dates coming from api in react datepicker?

Answer (score 0):

Just need to make a new array of dates coming from the api and pass that array to the `highlighDates` array like below:

```
<DatePicker
    className="form-control"
    selected={this.state.dateFilter}
    onChange={this.handleDateFilterChange}
    dateFormat="dd-MMMM-yyyy"
    highlightDates={this.state.highlightWithRanges}
/>
```

**this.state.highlighWithRanges** is my new array and i passed it to **highlightDates property**